# Mapping snippet trigger in visual mode

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

I'm using the UltiSnips plugin. When selecting text, you can press the trigger key to enter Insert mode, and the deleted text can then be used in a subsequent snippet. The snippet I'm using is as following:

```
snippet # "Put in brackets" i
\\${1:emph}{${VISUAL}$2}$0
endsnippet
```

So the way I use it is I select some text, press my trigger key (`<TAB>`), enter `#`, and press tab again. That works fine, but I want to map it a key (`<C-S-E>`), such that I can simply select the text and press that key to do the same thing.

I've tried different ways, but none of them work:
`vnoremap <buffer> <C-S-E>    #`   
`vnoremap <buffer> <C-S-E> :call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()#(<C-O>):call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()`

```
function! WrapBrack()
    call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()
    normal i#
    call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()
    return ''
endfunction

vnoremap <buffer><expr> <C-S-E> WrapBrack()
```

This last one says that it won't allow autocommand to write because it's not safe, and I don't want to overrule that.

I don't know what to try next, and I can't find helpful documentation. Also I'm not very good with VimScript.

Here's the plugin settings I have:

```
Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = '<s-tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnips", "my_snippets"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to call would be `UltiSnips#SaveLastVisualSelection()`, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/4f5249b2a6f6308377cb2bf734974a4e6f8a960e/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim#L64), or by inspecting the output of `:xnoremap <tab>`.

Modifying from your mapping, this would be

```
vnoremap <buffer> <C-S-E> :call UltiSnips#SaveLastVisualSelection()<CR>gvs#(<C-O>):call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<CR>
```

(remember to add a `<CR>` after a function is `:call`ed)

Note that, from my testing, the snippet expansion only occurs when the cursor is placed one character **after** the snippet trigger (`#` in your case). This means that using  and expanding in insert-normal mode may not work as expected (since the cursor would be on `#`, instead of after it). A more robust solution would be to use the expression register `<C-R>=`, that is

```
xnoremap <buffer> <C-S-E> :<C-U>call UltiSnips#SaveLastVisualSelection()<CR>gvs#<C-R>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<CR>
```

Comment: I just saw your answer after finding myself the reference you linked and finally making it work... To make sure there is no unexpected behavior, I also copied the use of `<C-R>=`, resulting in
`vnoremap <buffer> <C-S-E> :call UltiSnips#SaveLastVisualSelection()<CR>gvs#<C-R>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()`

Comment: Good point... using `<C-R>=` in place of what I proposed (`<space><Esc>`) is a better solution.. Let me update my answer to use `<C-R>=`.